# What was the first Esperanto telegram ever sent?

Tags: history

I remember somewhere reading that in some year Esperanto was approved as a language for use in telegraphy, so that it would cost less than being calculated as a telegram written in code, but currently can't find any information about that. What was the first telegram ever sent in Esperanto?

Answer (score 10):

Jen almenaŭ parta respondo al via informpeto: laŭ *Enciklopedio de Esperanto* en 1924 Ligo de Nacioj rekomendis al Universala Poŝta Unio akcepti Esperanton kiel „klaran lingvon” kaj en 1925 ĝi efektive tion faris.